# Why is this function shown in uppercase?

Tags: c

Page 20 of IETF RFC 1662 shows some simple code for checking a FCS (Frame Check Sequence).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662

C is a case sensitive language. I'm curious as to why the function assert is shown in uppercase?

```
ASSERT(sizeof (u16) == 2);
```

Comment: Is that C? I don't see anywhere in there that says the code is C. I think it's just pseudo-C meant to be illustrative. But I haven't read the RFC, so this is me speculating after skimming it.

Comment: That's not valid C code (unless there's some standard I missed somewhere that allows `main()` with no return type and no parameters as a valid function declaration).

Comment: @KenWhite: C89 allows it.

Comment: It's not uncommon to make macros all uppercase.

Comment: There are some hints in the RFC (footnotes 7, 8, and 9, and the acknolwedgements) to point the origin of the sample code. Theoretically, if you have access to those old publications, you could put the code in context and see why they did it that way.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a (somewhat odd) choice by the author of the RFC.

There's a convention to use all-caps for macro names.  The `ASSERT` used in the code in the RFC is probably meant to be a macro.

C does have a standard `assert()` macro, defined in `<assert.h>` (which violates the above convention -- oh, well). That macro is disabled (does nothing) if the macro `NDEBUG is defined when`` is included. Perhaps the author of the RFC didn't want to deal with that complication.

I don't know the full history of the RFC, but the code might have been based on code that was written before ANSI C compilers were widely available. The author avoided using prototypes, which were introduced by the 1989 standard.

RFCs are intended for human readers. The meaning of, for example,

```
ASSERT(sizeof (u16) == 2);
```

is clear enough to a human reader, and that's all that really matters.  Source code in an RFC is not necessarily meant to be used without modification. The code is clearly at least C-like, but it could also be considered a kind of pseudo-code. Someone who wanted to use the code could easily define an `ASSERT()` macro, or modify the code to use the standard `assert()`.

Sheer speculation: It's also possible that the code was originally written for an implementation that provided a predefined `ASSERT()` macro, and the lack of portability wasn't caught.